# How to Install OpenGateway and Membrr

Tags: membrr

I'm trying to install Membrr and OpenGateway on an existing EE site to allow us to accept payments through PayPal for subscriptions to different Member Groups. I'm following the instructions documented by Membrr and OpenGateway here:

http://www.membrr.com/docs/installation

First I'm wondering what license.txt file I should upload as there is no license now that OpenGateway is open source and I didn't pay them or Membrr for one. Does this mean that I should upload an arbitrary license.txt file? I've tried uploading one with filler text and am unsure if this is somehow holding up the install.

Second, I've tried going through the install steps and was unsuccessful in accessing /install directory (step 6 in docs)—browsing to the path only led me to my site's 404 page. Assuming the license.txt file isn't affecting this are there any other ways I could troubleshoot why this isn't working?

I've done all other steps outlined in the installation.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

We do not recommend using Membrr and OG.  You have two seperate system, two logins and it is a big pain.  There is a reason it is now FREE.  You get what you pay for.  If you are just using PayPal why not just use EE native Simple Commerce?

Comment: It was my feeling that Simple Commerce was too limited because users have to be logged in for PayPal's Instant Payment Notification to send notification emails. This means I'd have to sign users up, then send them to a form then send them to PayPal when I was hoping to integrate it all. I do appreciate your advice though, and Membrr may end up being an unreliable solution.

Comment: We had many issue with it Yawner.  Just my experience.  If it would work without Open Gateway it would be like 300% better.  Can you use the Charge add-on?  It does simple memberships and uses Stripe.  Much better processor and Joel is awesome (the developer).

Comment: Hey Bryan, I really appreciate the advice. I was looking into Charge and CartThrob but they're too expensive for our needs. The site is going to go through a total re-design and potentially re-build so something like that would have to wait until then since we don't really need all the functionality and can't justify the expense before a re-build.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download everything from github? If so you should not need license.txt file...

I'm guessing that your error has to do with something else.

if you have place opengateway in the root of your site then you should access:

http://www.mysite.com/opengateway/install

Comment: I didn't download from GitHub, I will try that, although I did try accessing that directory when I initially tried the install.

Comment: If you give me your contact info I could try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Have you built the server with IonCube Loader installed? We accidentally skipped over this the first time...

Comment: I  checked with my server support and they said it's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Membrr with PayPal in the past and had zero issues. I was really impressed with the functionality & flexibility. It's true that it's now abandon-ware, but the main issue with that as far as I can see is if EE changes in a way to make it stop working. I have also used aMember which worked, but is less integrated with EE than Membrr is.

I wish Ellislab would take over Membrr and just build it into EE, just sell it as an extra like the forum. Paid memberships is such an important feature to so many applications these days, especially serving media (sound and video). EE with its customisable fields  really lends it's self to that kind of application. I built a paid video podcast site a few years ago with EE and aMember and it worked really great! Even having EE serve content directly to iTunes.